# JTDS with absolute path (JDBC connection to an Access MDB File)

Tags: sql, ms-access, jtds

I've spent lots of time searching a solution to this, tried Google it, BING it, tried JTDS community but no solution, or maybe I haven't searched enough, nevertheless this is my situation:

I have the JTDS library in my project, and want to connect to a local MDB database file located at a local folder (C:\path\to\databasefile.mdb), but all I see is that I need the following connection String:

```
"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://url:port[;option1]..."
```

I want to use something like this:

```
"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[C:\\path\to\databasefile.mdb]:port[;option1]..."
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moved into using Jackcess... http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/

I needed a solution to read/write access local databases, which a jdbc-odbc bridge on a 64 bit machine cannot be accomplished.

Comment: Re: "read/write access local databases, which a jdbc-odbc bridge on a 64 bit machine cannot [do]." - Regardless of whether that statement was true at the time it was written it is not true now. Under most circumstances 64-bit Java applications can read/write Access database files using the JDBC/ODBC Bridge and the 64-bit version of the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255). The ODBC driver name is `{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}`.

Answer (score 6):

jTDS is only there to connect to a running Microsoft or Sybase SQL **Server**. 
It cannot read or write (local) MDB files.

The only way you can connect to an Access database through a JDBC driver is to use the JDBC/ODBC bridge with an url like this:

```
jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\path\to\databasefile.mdb
```